# No Such Partitions

Tags: boot-partition

I have a Problem I cant access Ubuntu I am New to Ubuntu when I boot my computer I get no such partitions on grub rescue I have not delete any files I accidentally change my partitions.

Comment: "I accidentally change my partitions" in the sense ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and choose try Ubuntu.

Open a terminal from the Live DVD/USB, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on Recommended repair.

Follow the instructions then reboot

More info here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i do not have a disk drive

Comment: Use a usb, the same one you used to install Ubuntu